# Perform operation by reading file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, data-structures, architecture

I have an action script(flat text file) in which every line is one operation. I would like to read this file line by line and trigger a operation for each line to perform the action defined in the file.

**Question**

Is there any design pattern or architecture perfectly suitable for this purpose ? Or whats the best way to do this?

I was thinking about creating thread for each single operation. Is that over killing the system?

**NOTE**

Some operation defined in file are very resource intensive while others are not.

Answer (score 1):

One thread per operation is overkill. Better to submit operations as separate tasks to thread pool (Java's default or your own).

Comment: Is there any design pattern or architecture that best suits for this kind of operation ?

Comment: Java 8 has good concurrency updates that could be useful especially CompletableFuture. You can use different thread pools for different kind of jobs (resource intensive vs non-resource intensive)

Comment: Thank you @AndyDufresne. I will have a look at it.